# "The response has already been committed" Error - chain.doFilter()

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, redirect, servlet-filters

I want to authorize users with a login page. I have created one login page, `login.jsp`, and it has login form. When I submit the form its value is redirected to a check servlet, and the servlet sets the session UserName if the user is valid.

I intercept this request through a filter and want to redirect the page after `chain.doFilter` but I got an error message that the response is already committed. What is the problem ?

```
HttpServletRequest req=(HttpServletRequest) request;
HttpServletResponse res=(HttpServletResponse) response;

if(req.getRequestURI().contains("/ShowHome"))  {

  chain.doFilter(req, res);

  if(req instanceof HttpServletRequest) {

      boolean authorized=false;

      HttpSession session= req.getSession(false);

      if(session!=null) {
        if(session.getAttribute("UserName")!=null) {
          authorized=true;
        }
      } else {
        authorized=false;
      }

    if(authorized) {
      System.out.println("You are authorized user ");
      res.sendRedirect("/FilterAuth/welcome.jsp");
    } else {
      System.out.println("authentication failed ! ");

      try {
        //response.flushBuffer();

        RequestDispatcher disp= request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        disp.forward(request, response);
        return;
      } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code... regarding your question: the response has already been commited by functions the `doChain` method forwarded to. E.g. the filter forwarded to a servlet that issued a redirect command.

Comment: Fixed your code up for you (pending review), but you are missing the close `}` for your first 2 `if`s. Is there any code down there, or just the `}`s?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the servlet filter when called before the servlet should do the authorization stuff. Once successful, should pass the call via chain.doFilter(req, res).

res.sendRedirect() shouldn't be called in the servlet filter. This simply indicates that the response has been committed.

The proper mapping in web.xml ensures that the required filter is called before calling the servlet. Later in the servlet if any redirect is required then it can be achieved.